# I am trying to use tab controller in flutter how can I access it inside the build context

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

[image: code image]

I am trying to use a tab bar controller , what is the right way to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the `tabController` globally inside your state class and initialise it inside init state as you did, then you can access it inside your build method.

```
late TabController tabController;

void initState(){
   tabController=TabController(vsync:this,length:3); 
}
```

now use accordingly tab controller inside build method.

Comment: I tried tried but it showed me an error that "No TabController for TabBarView.
"

Comment: and "tabbar" initialzation inside initstate showed to me that it is not used

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare tabController globally inside your state class and init it inside init state see the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) for more details  :

```dart
class _JobApplication... extendes State<...> ..{

   late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare in state

```
late TabController _tabController;
```

Assign in initstate

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }
```